Get URL for current design that includes version number
I know I can follow these steps to show the file version history sidebar:
https://help.figma.com/hc/en-us/articles/360038006754-View-a-file-s-version-history#h_01HAW5W5YMBX6RK90E84RKBQ2P
And I know I can share a version using these steps:
https://help.figma.com/hc/en-us/articles/360038006754-View-a-file-s-version-history#h_01HAW5W5YMA95B98HV3C2SBHS2
However, when I follow these steps, there’s no Copy Link option for the Current version. At one level, that makes sense, since in the browser, the address bar contains a link to the current version.
However, what I’m looking for is the current version such that it includes the current version-id.
For example -
https://www.figma.com/design/:fileId/FileDescrition?version-id=5662857941&node-id=1-3304&node-type=canvas&t=:anotherId
By copying the address bar value, the version-id is not included. And if the design changes, then the URL that was copied from the browser address bar no longer reflects what I was looking at the time I earlier copied it. The URL without the version-id is “evergreen”, always showing the latest. I’m looking for the current latest version, at a given point in time. How would I get that?  Open to manual steps and any API (e.g. plugin) that may help.
